# UnknownError: Failed to rename:

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
 def save_weights(self,  filename = "./" + str(timestamp) + "-tfsave"):  
    ### save model weights
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(self.sess, filename)
    print("saved to:",filename)
```

---

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
1366     except errors.OpError as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
1351

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1443                                             run_metadata)
1444

UnknownError: Failed to rename: ./2020-10-15_18:28-tfsave.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate9752799594239982307 to: ./2020-10-15_18:28-tfsave.data-00000-of-00001 : The parameter is incorrect.
; Unknown error
[[{{node save/SaveV2}}]]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You have some characters that are not allowed in the name of a file. At least, you need to remove `:` from the filename that comes from the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your name has some characters that are not allowed in filenames including `:` and `.`